# Keyboard not resigning second time?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

Keyboard not resigning second time on the same `textfield`. I used `UITextFieldDelegate`. For Ex: I enter something in `Name` `textField` and I resign the keyboard. I clicked in `MobileNo` field entered something. This time keyboard not resigning.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: how many textField you have to created?

Comment: make sure that delegate of all textfield is connected

Comment: Check your log either you have missed to set delegate of all 7 textfields or your app is crashing.

Comment: problem is definitly with delegate

Answer (score 1):

Make `delegate` of your `MobileNo`

```
MobileNo.delegate=self;
```

Or if your are using xib then make `Outlet` connection of `delegate`

Comment: disconnect and connect again?

Comment: i am sure it is not get crashed.get connected to all text

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}
-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
 [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```